# Tried to bold, centralise and underline the columns, and also clear the columns after generate order

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to **1)** Centre and underline the Column E and F in Order List sheet, from line 22 up to the blank line. **2)** Bold and centre the **VAT** and **Total** in the spreadsheet. **3)** Clear Column G28 afterwards in the other sheets after generate Order List. However, it is not underlined or centralised or bolded. Could you please take a look for me? Here is my code below. Many thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_info()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet

With Sheets("Order List")
.Cells.Clear
.Range("A21") = "PART CODE"
.Range("B21") = "DESCRIPTION"
.Range("C21") = "PRICE"
.Range("D21") = "QUANTITY"
.Range("E21") = "NET AMOUNT"
.Range("F21") = "SHEET NAME"
.Range("A21:F21").Font.Bold = True
End With

j = 22

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Order List" And sh.Name <> "INDEX" And sh.Name <> "SELECTOR" Then
        lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 28 To lastRow
            If sh.Range("G" & i) > 0 Then
                sh.Range("b" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order List").Range("A" & j)
                sh.Range("e" & i & ":g" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order List").Range("B" & j)
                Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j) = Sheets("Order List").Range("C" & j) * Sheets("Order List").Range("D" & j)
                Sheets("Order List").Range("F" & j) = sh.Name
                Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 1) = ""
                Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2) = "VAT".bold.center
                Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j + 1) = ""
                Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j + 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("E:E"))
                Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 3) = "TOTAL".bold.center                    Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j + 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("E:E"))

                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next sh
Sheets("Order List").Columns("A").AutoFit
Sheets("Order List").Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 90
Sheets("Order List").Columns("C:D").AutoFit
Sheets("Order List").Columns("E:F").AutoFit.Underline.Center

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
   If sh.Name <> "Order List" And sh.Name <> "INDEX" And sh.Name <> "SELECTOR" Then
        lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 28 To lastRow
          If sh.Range("G" & i) > 0 Then
          sh.Range("G" & i).Select
          Selection.ClearContents
    End If
   Next i
End If
Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit strange - you have `Option Explicit` on the top and thus your code should not be working at all, because of the compiling errors. The VBEditor should show you where they are exactly, once you try to run the code.

Here is one example:

In stead of:

```
Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2) = "VAT".bold.center
```

Write:

```
Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2).value = "VAT"
Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2).Font.Bold = True
Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

Then you can improve it further like this:

```
With Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2)
    .value = "VAT"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```

Or even write a separate function, to which you are passing only the range and the string.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. It does solve my problem. However, it is now showing error 400. Could you please let me know how to solve it? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do everything at the same time(bold and center in the first part, center and underline at the bottom). This doesn't work in VBA. It is necessary to take just one action after another.

One possible solution to your problem could be this:

```
Sub copy_info()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    With Sheets("Order List")
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A21") = "PART CODE"
        .Range("B21") = "DESCRIPTION"
        .Range("C21") = "PRICE"
        .Range("D21") = "QUANTITY"
        .Range("E21") = "NET AMOUNT"
        .Range("F21") = "SHEET NAME"
        .Range("A21:F21").Font.Bold = True
    End With

    j = 22

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            If sh.Name <> "Order List" And sh.Name <> "INDEX" And sh.Name <> "SELECTOR" Then
                lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                For i = 28 To lastRow
                    If sh.Range("G" & i) > 0 Then
                        sh.Range("b" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order List").Range("A" & j)
                        sh.Range("e" & i & ":g" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order List").Range("B" & j)
                        Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j) = Sheets("Order List").Range("C" & j) * Sheets("Order List").Range("D" & j)
                        Sheets("Order List").Range("F" & j) = sh.Name
                        Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 1) = ""
                        Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2) = "VAT"
                        Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2).Font.Bold = True
                        Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

                        Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j + 1) = ""
                        Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j + 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("E:E"))
                        Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 3) = "TOTAL"
                        **Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 3).Font.Bold = True
                        Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter**

                        Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j + 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("E:E"))

                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Next sh
        Sheets("Order List").Columns("A").AutoFit
        Sheets("Order List").Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 90
        Sheets("Order List").Columns("C:D").AutoFit
        Sheets("Order List").Columns("E:F").AutoFit
        Sheets("Order List").Columns("E:F").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Sheets("Order List").Columns("E:F").Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle

        For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
           If sh.Name <> "Order List" And sh.Name <> "INDEX" And sh.Name <> "SELECTOR" Then
                lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                For i = 28 To lastRow
                  If sh.Range("G" & i) > 0 Then
                  sh.Range("G" & i).Select
                  Selection.ClearContents
            End If
           Next i
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. It does solve my problem. However, it is now showing error 400. Could you please let me know how to solve it? Many thanks